# Appropriate Inputs for Snake Game Artificial Neural Network

Tags: neural-network

I am trying to build a snake game using artificial neural network. I want to know what are the possible inputs. I am planning to input the direction of the apple relative to snake head? But what will be this value? Like it the apple is 90 degree right of snake? can i give it value 0.25 and when the apple is 180 relative to snake head, can i give input as 0.5 and values in between based on this?

I am a beginner only want to use simple backpropagation algorithm not the q-learning algorithm.

Is it necessary to give distance to apple as an input?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider this for training:

1. distance and angle from head to apple
2. what is on the left from his head
3. what is on the front of his head
4. what is on the right from his head

Also you can take this as reference- [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2_CPB0uBkc)